# Can a meromorphic function which does not have any poles in a domain be shown to be bounded in that domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Basically such a function would not have any singularities in that domain and is completely analytic on it. Then, is the function bounded on that domain?

Comment: What about $f(z)=z$ on $\mathbb C$? Or $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb C - \{0\}$?

Comment: I may say something trivially wrong, but doesn't that fall under [Liouville's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) (at least in the case of $\mathbb{C}$)? I.e., if it's bounded then it is constant.

Comment: @ClementC. You are right, if it can be shown to be bounded on the entire complex plane then it's constant, and for that only I want to know whether this can be shown to be bounded in the domain. Also I forgot to add that the function is doubly periodic, if that helps somehow. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Krish the domain is bounded, not an infinite one.

Comment: @Deven: Not sure to understand fully, though. What prevents one to take a meromorphic function $f$ on an open set $D$ with a single pole at say  $x_0$, and define $g$ as the restriction of $f$ to $D\setminus \{x_0\}$?

Comment: Not sure, I quite understand your point, but my question is basically the restriction g that you have defined, would it be bounded?

Comment: Well, $f$ goes to infinity at $x_0$, so $g$ does as well (the fact that $x_0$ is not in the domain of $f$ does not prevent $g(z)$ from going to infinity as $z$ goes closer to $x_0$).

Comment: @Deven Please define domain.

Comment: Let us avoid such functions and say talk about functions which never did have any poles to begin with, my question is if the meromorphic function did not have any poles as well, would then it be analytic and whether is an analytic function bounded on a bounded domain.

Comment: @GitGud we can limit domain to be the basis parallelogram of an elliptic function or any connected domain, nice plain rectangular region would do.

Comment: @Deven I asked for it because I think some people are interpreting domain as in domain of a function instead of [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_%28mathematical_analysis%29) as in a connected set. Perhaps it is a good idea to add to the question what you mean exactly.

Comment: It seems to be pretty common terminology (especially in the context of complex analysis), that a domain just means a connected open set. Anyway, in the case you are describing now, you can certainly assert that your function is locally bounded

Comment: @Elliot and suppose if we do not count the boundaries of the parallelogram, then the domain is no longer compact as it is open now, would then my case hold? (that the function is locally bounded) or would I have to consider boundaries separately somehow?

Comment: @Deven yes, to be locally bounded in your open parallelogram means that you are bounded on any compact subset of your open domain. Away from poles, meromorphic functions are analytic hence continuous it will be locally bounded in any compact subset of your domain